# sql server 2008 Pivot View

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
create view Vw_sub

as

DECLARE
 @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select

 @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(subjectname) 
                    from Vw_Subtem where ClassID=1 and SchoolId=4 and SectionId=1
                    group by subjectname, id
                    order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select  subjectname
                from Vw_Subtem
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(subjectname)
                for subjectname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
go
```

**I have a Err"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'." At the time create View Plz Give me A solution How to Create View Of this**

Answer (score 1):

A view has to be a single SELECT statement. You can read up on this in the definition of [CREATE VIEW for SQL Server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

More formally the syntax is:

```
CREATE VIEW [ schema_name . ] view_name [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ] 
[ WITH <view_attribute> [ ,...n ] ] 
AS select_statement 
[ WITH CHECK OPTION ] [ ; ]
```

You can see you create a VIEW as a select_statement. You can supply any select statement, and no more.

If you require dynamic SQL to generate the statement, your only option is to use Stored Procedures.